# Is there a way to make the git Bash connect to the heroku server using my University proxy address?

Tags: git, heroku

Could you help me be able to connect to the heroku so that I can be able to login credentials into my Heroku account?

I want to be able to also commit and git download my files using the University proxy:

```
proxy.uonbi.ac.ke
```

That proxy has a password of the form `xxx@students`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to contact an heroku remote repo, this article "[Heroku Behind a Proxy](http://kitmonisit.com/2012/11/proxychains-heroku/)", from [Kit Monisit](https://github.com/kitmonisit) mentions that:

- even exporting `http_proxy` statements in your `bash_profile` isn't enough
- a tool like **[procychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/)** is needed: see its [howto page](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/howto.html)

> A tool that forces any TCP connection made by any given application to follow through proxy like TOR or any other SOCKS4, SOCKS5 or HTTP(S) proxy.
>
> When you want two (or more) different proxies in chain:
> like:

```
your_host <--> proxy 1 (TOR) <--> proxy 2 (HTTP or SOCKS4/5) <--> target_host
```

> You may need it when the only way out from your LAN is through proxy server.
> Or to get out from behind restrictive firewall that filters some ports in outgoing traffic.
> And you want to do that with some app like telnet.

In your case:

> Part of the problem is that the Heroku client uses HTTPS to log in remotely.
>
> To work around this, you can use ProxyChains to tunnel HTTPS connections through your restrictive proxy server.
> Its role is to provide proxy authentication services for software that otherwise cannot work with proxies.

The article explains the build and installation.

The setup is something along the lines of:

> Copy the `proxychains.conf` file to your home directory.

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir .proxychains
$ cd ~/dev/build/proxychains
$ cp etc/proxychains.conf ~/.proxychains
```

> Configure the proxy server address.

```
$ cd ~/.proxychains
$ vim proxychains.conf
```

> Comment out the following line so that it looks like

```
#proxy_dns
```

> Towards the end of the file, below the header `[ProxyList]`, add your proxy server in the following format:

```
type host port [user pass]
```

> For example

```
http 12.34.56.78 8080 user_me pa55w0rd
```

> In your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`, delete or comment out any export statements that set the proxy server for the terminal session. For example

```
# export http_proxy="http://user:pass@host.com:8080"
```

Note: if you have a **[special character in your password](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/guides/getting-started/special-characters-in-usernames-and-passwords)** (like an "[at sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign)"), you need to have those characters **[percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-escape)**:

```
] [ ? / < ~ # ` ! @ $ % ^ & * ( ) + = } | : " ; ' , > { space
```

Your "`@`" in a password would be `%40`: `xxx%40students`.

> Test your setup with Heroku

```
$ cd
$ proxychains heroku login
```